# How to use bootstrap accordion in fullpage.js

Tags: accordion, fullpage.js

I wanna use an accordion inside a fullpage.js section
but it doesn't work

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    navigation: true,
    navigationPosition: 'right',
    responsiveSlides: false,
//does not work
    lockAnchors: true,
});

//strange, it works but I get a js error -> fullpage_api is not defined
fullpage_api.setLockAnchors(true);
```

Comment: caching problems - everything works fine